# ASP.NET Core 7 Razor page filter not applied to Index.cshtml in root folder

Tags: asp.net-core, filter, razor-pages

I have this validate session page filter to check if user's session expired:

```
namespace SYNT.IBP.PageFilters
{
    public class ValidateSessionPageFilter : IPageFilter
    {
        public void OnPageHandlerSelected(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnPageHandlerExecuting(PageHandlerExecutingContext context)
        {
            bool sessionExpired = true;

            var loginUser = context.HttpContext.Session.GetData<LoginUserInfoModel>(constSSKey_LoginUserInfo);

            if (loginUser != null)
            {
                if (loginUser.LOGIN_MODE_ID > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginUser.LOGIN_ID))
                {
                    sessionExpired = false;
                }
            }

            if (sessionExpired)
            {
                bool isAjax = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";

                context.Result = !isAjax ? new RedirectToPageResult(constPage_PageExpired) : new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }

        public void OnPageHandlerExecuted(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And in `Program.cs`, I have applied the filter to the `/ADMIN` folder:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddFolderApplicationModelConvention("/ADMIN", model => model.Filters.Add(new ValidateSessionPageFilter()));
});
```

I have the following folder structure:

[Page folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN9Do.jpg)

So far, session validation is working for pages inside the sub folders of `/ADMIN`. However it is not triggered on `Index.cshtml` in the root folder.

Any idea what went wrong? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: When you access `/admin/index`, you project will not hit `OnPageHandlerExecuting` in `ValidateSessionPageFilter` ? I test your code and everything goes well.

Comment: I have done further testing. After I clicked on the Logout button, I will be routed to a logout page. 

If I was at a page say /ADMIN/SYS/Payment/Listing previously, when I clicked on the Back button of the browser  page, the Page Expired page will be shown automatically. 

However, if my last page was at /ADMIN/Index page, then, the page filter won't work (Index OnGet event also not triggered). I suspect it is something to do with the browser history.

Comment: It seems to related to cache in your browser, I reproduce this situation, But when i disable cache in my browser, When i click back button to return `Admin/index` page, It can hit filter correctly.